# Sliding UIView When Keyboard Appears in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I know there are a lot of similar questions on here about sliding a UIView when the keyboard appears on iOS. However, I seem to be having an issue with my implementation that I haven't seen mentioned. When my slide animation occurs, it doesn't start from the top of the screen as I would expect, but rather, starts from a lower origin and moves back up to the top of the screen.

[image: UIView Sliding Incorrectly]

Here's the class extension I've created to achieve this slide-up behavior.

```
public extension UIViewController {

    private dynamic func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        if view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            slideViewVerticallyForKeyboardHeight(sender, directionUp: true)
        }
    }

    private dynamic func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        if view.frame.origin.y < 0 {
            slideViewVerticallyForKeyboardHeight(sender, directionUp: false)
        }
    }

    private func slideViewVerticallyForKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification, directionUp: Bool) {
        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().height ?? 0.0
        let animationDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.doubleValue ?? 0.0
        let animationCurve: Int = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]?.integerValue ?? 0
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: animationCurve)!)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)

        var newFrameRect = view.frame
        if directionUp {
            newFrameRect.origin.y -= keyboardHeight
            newFrameRect.size.height += keyboardHeight
        } else {
            newFrameRect.origin.y += keyboardHeight
            newFrameRect.size.height -= keyboardHeight
        }
        view.frame = newFrameRect
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }

    public func registerViewSlideOnKeyobard() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    public func unregisterViewSlideOnKeyboard() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Looking at my view.frame value, I have a negative origin.y as I would expect. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

**Edit**: User aimak made the very sensible suggestion that I change to the (not deprecated) block-call version of animation. Interestingly, the animation is still broken, but in a different way. Here is the modified code and a screen capture of what happens with the more up-to-date animation call.

[image]

```
private func slideViewVerticallyForKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification, directionUp: Bool) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().height ?? 0.0
    let animationDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.doubleValue ?? 0.0
    let animationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]?.integerValue ?? 0)!
    var newFrameRect = view.frame
    if directionUp {
        newFrameRect.origin.y -= keyboardHeight
        newFrameRect.size.height += keyboardHeight
    } else {
        newFrameRect.origin.y += keyboardHeight
        newFrameRect.size.height -= keyboardHeight
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0, options: animationCurve.toOptions(), animations: {
            self.view.frame = newFrameRect
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: demo link https://github.com/harshilkotecha/UIScrollViewWhenKeyboardAppearInSwift3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not fully help, but those animation methods are discouraged since iOS 4+ :

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/commitAnimations

Have you tried with the block-based API ?

Edit : It was autolayout issue !

Ok, I think I have it : do you use autolayout ? If so, the subviews of UIViewController.view probably have constraints to view.top = 0, and that constraint will never be broken. If you want to achieve the animation you'd want, consider : 1. embed every subview inside a scrollView (then animate the contentOffet.y change) or 2. remove/edit your view.top constraint

Comment: I just tried using the newer block-based API. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, but it does break in a different way. I've updated the original question with the results of using the block-based API.

Comment: Ok, I think I have it : do you use autolayout ? If so, the subviews of UIViewController.view probably have constraints to view.top = 0, and that constraint will never be broken. If you want to achieve the animation you'd want, consider : 1. embed every subview inside a scrollView (then animate the contentOffet.y change) or 2. remove/edit your view.top constraint

Comment: Also, another "valid experimentation" (not really a solution, i would not advise to use it in production) would be to change the window's frame : `self.view.window?.frame = newFrameRect`

Comment: Yep, it was autolayout that was giving me grief. I've done the task of embedding everything in a ScrollView and that works great! Thanks. I'll mark this as the answer an post the relevant answer code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as aimak pointed out, was that I was using AutoLayout and the constraints were overriding my modification of the frame. To solve this, I moved all my content into a scrollview. I now utilizing scrolling the scrollview to offset when the keyboard shows.

[image]

Here is the helper class I have to provide the scrolling behavior. Note that I pass in the scroll view now.

```
public class KeyboardScrollViewHelper {

    private var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    private var isScrolled = false

    private dynamic func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        guard !isScrolled else {
            return
        }

        slideViewVerticallyForKeyboardHeight(sender, directionUp: true)
    }

    private dynamic func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        guard isScrolled else {
            return
        }

        slideViewVerticallyForKeyboardHeight(sender, directionUp: false)
    }

    private func slideViewVerticallyForKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification, directionUp: Bool) {

        guard let scrollView = self.scrollView else {
            return
        }

        let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().height ?? 0.0
        let animationDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.doubleValue ?? 0.0
        let animationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]?.integerValue ?? 0)!
        var scrollViewOffset: CGFloat = 0
        if directionUp {
            scrollViewOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y + keyboardHeight
            isScrolled = true
        } else {
            scrollViewOffset =  scrollView.contentOffset.y - keyboardHeight
            isScrolled = false
        }

        scrollViewOffset = max(0, scrollViewOffset)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0, options: animationCurve.toOptions(), animations: {
            scrollView.contentOffset.y = scrollViewOffset
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    public func registerViewSlideOnKeyobard(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.scrollView = scrollView
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    public func unregisterViewSlideOnKeyboard() {
        scrollView?.contentOffset = CGPointZero

        scrollView = nil
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```